# bad output of canvas generated image

Tags: javascript, html, image, video, video-thumbnails

SO the code below is simply meant to allow users upload a video and then when the press the button 'choose thumbnail' an image is generated from a canvas which represents the current image which was showing when the video was playing...that is,the image becomes the thumbnail of the video which the user chooses by seeking a particular video time,pauses the video and creates the thumbnail which is an image of the video when it was paused.

Everything is going fine except that the image is too long..in a way...the  image is created in the dimensions that I want BUT some a lot of extra white space is still counted as the image....that is a lot of white space round it is the image.

This screenshots may help...

```js
var _CANVAS = document.querySelector("#myCanvas"),
  _CTX = _CANVAS.getContext("2d"),
  _VIDEO = document.querySelector("#main-video");

document.getElementById("image").src = _CANVAS.toDataURL();


function showit() {
  document.getElementById("other").style.display = 'block';

}
// Upon click this should should trigger click on the #file-to-upload file input element
// This is better than showing the not-good-looking file input element
document.querySelector("#diver").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector("#file-to-upload").click();
});

// When user chooses a MP4 file
document.querySelector("#file-to-upload").addEventListener('change', function() {
  // Validate whether MP4
  if (['video/mp4'].indexOf(document.querySelector("#file-to-upload").files[0].type) == -1) {
    alert('Error : Only MP4 format allowed');
    return;
  }

  // Hide upload button
  document.querySelector("#upload-button").style.display = 'none';

  // Object Url as the video source
  document.querySelector("#main-video source").setAttribute('src', URL.createObjectURL(document.querySelector("#file-to-upload").files[0]));

  // Load the video and show it
  _VIDEO.load();
  _VIDEO.style.display = 'inline';

  // Load metadata of the video to get video duration and dimensions
  _VIDEO.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    console.log(_VIDEO.duration);
    var video_duration = _VIDEO.duration,
      duration_options_html = '';

    // Set options in dropdown at 4 second interval
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(video_duration); i = i + 2) {
      duration_options_html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    document.querySelector("#set-video-seconds").innerHTML = duration_options_html;

    // Show the dropdown container
    document.querySelector("#thumbnail-container").style.display = 'block';

    // Set canvas dimensions same as video dimensions
    _CANVAS.width = _VIDEO.videoWidth;
    _CANVAS.height = _VIDEO.videoHeight;
  });
});

// On changing the duration dropdown, seek the video to that duration
document.querySelector("#set-video-seconds").addEventListener('change', function() {
  _VIDEO.currentTime = document.querySelector("#set-video-seconds").value;

  // Seeking might take a few milliseconds, so disable the dropdown and hide download link

});

// Seeking video to the specified duration is complete
document.querySelector("#main-video").addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  // Re-enable the dropdown and show the Download link
  document.querySelector("#set-video-seconds").disabled = false;
  document.querySelector("#get-thumbnail").style.display = 'inline';
});

// On clicking the Download button set the video in the canvas and download the base-64 encoded image data
document.querySelector("#get-thumbnail").addEventListener('click', function() {

  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(_VIDEO, 1, 1, _VIDEO.videoWidth / 8, _VIDEO.videoHeight / 8);
  document.getElementById("image").src = c.toDataURL();


});

document.querySelector("#get-thumbnail").setAttribute('href', c.toDataURL());
document.querySelector("#get-thumbnail").setAttribute('download', 'thumbnai.png');
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#video-demo-container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

#main-video {
  display: none;
  max-width: 400px;
}

#thumbnail-container {
  display: none;
}

#get-thumbnail {
  display: none;
}

#video-canvas {
  display: block;
}

#upload-button {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

#file-to-upload {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="border:2px dashed blue;" id="diver">

    <div id="video-demo-container">
      <button id="upload-button">Select MP4 Video</button>
      <input type="file" id="file-to-upload" accept="video/mp4" />
      <video id="main-video" controls>
  <source type="video/mp4">
 </video>

      <p id="yes"></p>

    </div>


  </div>
  <p id="thumbnail-container"><button onclick="showit()">Confirm</button> <button>Undo</button></p>

  <br>


  <!-- other content to choose -->
  <div style="border:2px solid green;display:none" id="other">
    <br>
    <div style="margin-left:10%;">
      <p style="font-size:160%">
        <font style="font-weight:bolder">(1)</font>Choose thumbnail</p>

      <font style="font-weight:bolder;margin-left:3%;">(a)Choose from video clip:</font><br><br>

      <div id="allfloat">

        <div style="margin-left:5%;">
          Seek to
          <select id="set-video-seconds"></select> seconds <br><br>

          <button id="get-thumbnail" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;background-color:blue;padding-left,padding-right:2%;color:white;">Create Thumbnail</button>
        </div>






        <p style="font-weight:bolder;margin-left:5%;">Thumbnail:</p>

        <img id="image" src width="200%" height="200%" style="margin-left:5%">


        

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display:none;">
 Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
 </canvas>
```

u see what I'm talking about.the image is somehow so large but I can't see the 'large part' of the image.

Also,I don't know what they mean as 'c is undefined'

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you checked the data for width and height passed for the image generation ?

Comment: @Mosè Raguzzini  Yes but is directly related to the canvas dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1)** Fix *`c is undefined`* error :

Cut the `var c` and `var ctx` declarations from *`//On clicking the Download button`* section and paste them with your other var declarations. This will give it global access (not just local access for only that specific function) :

```
// when you do this part
var _CANVAS = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
var _CTX = _CANVAS.getContext("2d");
var _VIDEO = document.querySelector("#main-video");

// also add this part below it
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
```

**(2)** Fix scale or quality :

When drawing the thumbnail with `ctx.drawImage`, use values of `c.width` and `c.height`. Example:

```
// On clicking the Download button set the video in the canvas and download the base-64 encoded image data
document.querySelector("#get-thumbnail").addEventListener('click', function() {

ctx.drawImage(_VIDEO, 1, 1, c.width, c.height); //use c.width not _VIDEO.videoWidth... etc
document.getElementById("image").src = c.toDataURL();

});
```

That should give a clear image at same size as video resolution.

Let me know how it goes. Thanks.